# Removing extended ASCII characters. Linux script (128-255)

Tags: linux, extended-ascii

I want to remove in my text any kind of ASCII character with code in interval [128-255]. 
gsub(/[^a-z]/, "", $0) --This is how I remove everything except the letters;
gsub(/ē|é|ě|è|ū|ú|ǔ|ù|ǖ|ǘ|ǚ|ǜ|ü|ō|ó|ǒ|ò|ī|í|ǐ|ì|ā|á|ǎ|à|å|ä|â/, "", $0) -- This is how I remove some extended characters, but not every. 
gsub(/"[\128-\255]"/, "", $0) I am trying this, but it shows me an error, invalid interval. So, can anybody please help with that problem. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslash codes must be in octal, or prefixed with a `x` and in hexadecimal.

```
\200-\377
\x80-\xff
```

Or you could just use `strings`.

Comment: It actually did not work, but I just used a brute force method, I copied every possible lower case extended ASCII character and removed it. :D Thanks anyway, your solution seems alright, but I do not know why it is not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

The `\nnn` syntax is octal (where `n` is `0-7`), so:

```
\128 = invalid octal
\200 = 128
\255 = 173
\377 = 255
```

So you want:

```
\200-\377
```